# DQL\SQL query in Symfony2. Many tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a question about DQL query.

I have these tables: 'orders', 'orders_kitchen', 'orders_institution' and 'variants'.

From the table 'variants', I get order IDs that have already been made offers.

```
$orders = $em->createQuery("SELECT o
                FROM AppBundle:Orders o
                JOIN AppBundle:OrdersInstitution oi
                WHERE oi.idInstittuion = :institution AND o.idorder =                             oi.idOrder AND o.finalDeal IS NULL
                ORDER BY o.idorder DESC")
            ->setParameter("institution",$institution)->getResult();
```

When a customer leaves the order, he may proceed in three ways:

1. Do not add a record to the table 'orders_institution' some institutions going and add an entry in the table of certain types of cuisines id
2. Does not add an entry in any of the tables
3. Add an entry in the table 'orders_kitchen', some types of cuisines ID works with this institution

I need to find all orders that have not selected any one institution, and none of the types of cuisines, or at least one of the kitchen works with the institution (this can be an array).

And I don't want to choose orders whose ID is in the table 'variants'.

Comment: i don't understand well, it looks a bit messy, you want to select all order which have (no institution and no type of cuisine) or (have one type of kitchen and that kitchen should have institution) ?

Comment: its very heavily to tell.
I wona choose all orders with:
- don't have any cuisine or any institution;
- or have the cuisines with which this institution work;
- AND this orders ids are not in the query, which i took above

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with SQL something like (DQL doesnt performe well with lot of joins) :

```
   $sql =  'SELECT * FROM Orders o JOIN
(SELECT o1.id FROM Orders o1 WHERE o1.cuisine IS NULL OR o1.institution IS NULL) o1  JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Orders o2 INNER JOIN Cuisine c ON c.insitution_id =  '.$institution_id.') o2 JOIN (your query);';
```

Something like this should do it, not expert in SQL i usually end up trying until i get it !

I dont think its correct tho but at least its a start :p